# Bootstrap datetimepicker startDate and EndDate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to allow only selectable date on calender, start date as today date and end date as 'end;
below is my code, its not working pls advice

```
$(function() {
    var start = $('#start').val();
    var end = $('#end').val();

    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker(
        'setStartDate': today,
        'setEndDate':end);
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure your datetimepicker initialization is correct?, I think you are missing `{}` ..also you should bind your initialization to some event on the `end` input...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the docs at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate

There are no options called `setStartDate` or `setEndDate`.

You should use `minDate` and `maxDate`. For these options you can use `date`, `moment`, or `string`.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/2917/) with said options.

Edit. Also note that using `new Date()` will return the current time, so that should set your start date to today.

Answer (score 0):

You should use minDate and maxDate for this features

```
$(function() {
    var start = '20-Aug-2019 10:05';  
    var end = '30-Sep-2019 10:05';

    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format : 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm',
        minDate: today,
        maxDate:end,
     });
  });
```